# Using WebView and Adobe Flash Player plugin to play .swf flash doesn't work in Android 4.4.2?

Tags: android, webview, flash

In my project, I need to play some local .swf flash files that are in my assets folder. It works well in Android 4.1.1, but not in Android 4.4.2; it only shows a white screen.

I've searched the internet, and someone said that Android 4.4.2 doesn't support this kind of situation any more.

Here is my code

```
WebSettings webSettings = this.mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    mWebView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_main);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/flash/chinese_culture/main_culture.swf");
```

Whether I declare `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the AndroidManifest.xml or not, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Adobe and Android doesn't support Flash since Android 4.1 officially. You might be lucky that it works on 4.1.1, but since then, it's *officially* impossible. [Link to related article](http://www.techhive.com/article/260901/android_flash_player_rip_how_to_get_it_now_that_its_gone.html)

Comment: Thank you for your information.But do you have any other advice to solve this kind of problem.I just want to play the local .swf flash files.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any advice regarding this issue. You might read some related questions on the right, but I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Thank you very much and I will check the related articles on the right side.