# How to play swf file in java-android?

Tags: java, android, flash

I want to play flash file (SWF) in in android but I can't I use this code to show it in `WebView` but it not work for me.

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY); 
mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/game.swf");
```

Comment: Flash isn't supported on Android.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing you could do.

Answer (score 0):

First create a HTML file to load the swf:

game.html

```
<html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <object width="215" height="140">
      <param name="game" value="game.swf">
        <embed src="file:///android_asset/game.swf"
               width="215" height="140">
        </embed>
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then for the android part:

```
package webView.video;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
private WebView mWebView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super. onCreate (savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);



         // html file with sample swf video in sdcard

         //swf2.html points to swf in sdcard

         mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
         mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
         mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
         mWebView.loadUrl("yourHtmlfile.html");

     }
}
```

Saw it in this question [How to Play local swf files in a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106636/how-to-play-local-swf-files-in-a-webview)
credits goes to him...

Comment: it says "Couldn't load plug-in" and i install flash player on the phone but still it not work.

Comment: which version of android are u running ? I think after 4.1 its unlikely to work any flash in webview, I found it out in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293310/using-webview-and-adobe-flash-player-plugin-to-play-swf-flash-doesnt-work-in-a

Comment: so what should i do for playing SWF in android?

Comment: I dont think it will be possible right know at least until they update the android Webview to support it again.